# universal algorithm date ranges

Tags: algorithm, date, range

I tried to solve problem like below:
I have table where there are two columns, date_from and date_to. And there are few rows, for example

```
1   2016-08-01   2016-12-31
2   2017-01-01   2017-08-01
3   2017-08-02   2017-12-31
```

I need put the row inside between 2nd and 3rd row. with date range like one previous month, so result should be like for November:

```
1   2016-08-01   2016-12-31
2   2017-01-01   2017-08-01
3   2017-08-02   2017-09-30
4   2017-10-01   2017-10-31
5   2017-11-01   2017-12-31
```

What are the best and simple solution for task like above ?

thanks for feedback 
reagrds malin

Comment: Is your problem solved simply by sorting on `date_from`? What programming language are you using?

Comment: Ms SQL stored procedure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your table is defined like this:

```sql
create table periods (
    date_from date,
    date_until date
);
insert into periods values
  ('2016-08-01', '2016-12-31'),
  ('2017-01-01', '2017-08-01'),
  ('2017-08-02', '2017-12-31');
```

Then you could use this stored procedure:

```sql
create proc add_period(@add_from date, @add_until date) as
begin
    delete from periods
      where date_from  between @add_from and @add_until
      and   date_until between @add_from and @add_until;
    insert into periods(date_from, date_until) 
      select dateadd(day, 1, @add_until), date_until
      from   periods
      where  date_from < @add_from
      and    date_until > @add_until;
    update periods 
      set   date_until = dateadd(day, -1, @add_from)
      where @add_from between date_from and date_until;
    update periods
      set   date_from = dateadd(day, 1, @add_until)
      where @add_until between date_from and date_until;
    insert into periods(date_from, date_until) 
      values (@add_from, @add_until);
end;
go
```

You would call it like this:

```sql
exec add_period '2017-10-01','2017-10-31';
```